# Instance Data.Sequence with Haskell Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have the next problem with `Data.Sequence` and Aeson. I want to create my data `DraftVar` deriving `Generic`, which use `Data.Sequence` on the constructor `DV2`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, OverloadedStrings #-}

-- Imports

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

import qualified Data.Sequence as DS

-- Data

data DraftVar = 
    DV1 { dv1_val :: Int }
    | DV2 { dv2_list :: DS.Seq DraftVar }
    deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON DraftVar
instance FromJSON DraftVar
```

With this code, I receive and error that says: `No instance for (ToJSON (DS.Seq DraftVar))`. So I need to create a instance of `Data.Sequence` for the Aeson library.

On the `ToJSON` instance declaration, I decide to transform the `Data.Sequence` to a list. The code is:

```
import Data.Foldable as DF

instance (Show a) => ToJSON (DS.Seq a) where
    toJSON l = object [ "values" .=  show (DF.toList l) ]
```

But what happen, when I want to extract from this Json the list and then transform the data to `Data.Sequence`?

```
instance (Show a) => FromJSON (DS.Seq a) where
    parseJSON (Object o) = ???
```

Maybe I need a library or an special function from Aeson, I don't know. The most useful example (that I found) is this: [Parsing an Array with Haskell Aeson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742872/parsing-an-array-with-haskell-aeson)

Do you have a better approach?

Comment: You might also try upgrading; I think `aeson` has had `Seq` instances since 0.8.1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` and `Seq` are isomorphic via `fromList` / `toList` (they just have vastly different representations and performance characteristics), so the most straightforward way to implement `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` for `Seq` is by re-using the existing implementation for `[]`:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as DS
import Data.Foldable as DF

instance (ToJSON a) => ToJSON (DS.Seq a) where
    toJSON = toJSON . DF.toList

instance (FromJSON a) => FromJSON (DS.Seq a) where
    parseJSON = fmap DS.fromList . parseJSON
```

Comment: I saw @Ørjan's comment above that newer versions of `aeson` already have `Seq` instances, but I think the above is a general enough technique to merit an answer on its own.